# Continuous point map for spherical domains

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, complex-geometry, discrete-geometry

Consider the space $J$ of Jordan domains on the sphere $\textbf{S}^2$, i.e., continuous injective maps from the unit disk into $\textbf{S}^2$ modulo homeomorphisms of the disk. How can one construct a continuous map $f\colon J\to\textbf{S}^2$ which is equivariant under isometries of $\textbf{S}^2$, i.e., for every $\rho\in O(3)$ and $D\in J$, $f(\rho(D))=\rho(f(D))$?

For Jordan domains in Euclidean plane $\textbf{R}^2$, there are several examples for $f$ such as the center of mass, or circumcenter. But these notions do not seem to generalize readily to $\textbf{S}^2$.

**Notes:**

1. In a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08135) with Igor Belegradek, it was shown that $f$ exists for $C^1$ domains, using equivariant fiber bundle theory. We were also able to choose the points in the interior of the domains; however, the selection was not canonical.
2. $f$ does not exist if the topology on the domains is induced by Hausdorff distance and we stipulate that the point lies in the domain; see Remark 3.4 in the paper with Belegradek.
3. I first heard the question of continuous point selection from the interior of Jordan domains from Eugenio Calabi in 1995.

Comment: What if you take the centre of mass in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and project radially?

Comment: @Marco Golla, it does not work when the center of mass is at the origin.

Comment: I naively thought this could not happen---I can envision some counterexamples now.

Comment: Presumably you could run area preserving curve shortening flow which should converge to a circle in the geodesic circle in $S^2$ and then map to the center of the circle (with the ambiguity of which choice to make determined by the domain).  The only part that is not totally clear to me is the continuity, but that seems plausible.  This may be overkill of course.

Comment: @RBega, as far as I know curve shortening flow would require the curve to be rectifiable. Also I do not know how you would keep the area constant.

Comment: There is a well defined CSF for [Jordan curves](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.05704.pdf) in $\mathbb{S}^2$.  Not sure about making it area preserving. Though it might be possible to either use $\pm$ the extinction point or the center if the limit was a geodesic.

Comment: I guess the paper I linked required the image of the curve to have Lebesgue measure zero in order to have a unique evolution, though I'm an not totally sure how you define center of mass in a continuous fashion in this case either.

Comment: @RBega, I don't think that CSF is going to work even for smooth curves, because if we take a pair of smaller circles on either side of a great circle and parallel to it they will float towards antipodal points.

Comment: Yes, as I alluded to CSF will give you a pair of antipodal points (the singular point and its antipodal point or the two antipodal focal points of the geodesic) and you have to use the side the disk is on to select the ``correct" one.  I imagine this relates to a topological result about what happens when the curves are oriented or unoriented.

Comment: To define continuity of your f, you need to specify topology on J. What is it? Convergence defined by Hausdorff metric? You can have all sorts of weird limit in such topology.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko, the topology is already defined as the space of continuous injective maps from the disk to the sphere modulo homeomorphisms of the disk. So two domains are close provided that they admit parameterizations which are $C^0$ close. This is different from Hausdorff topology, where as you  say bad things happen.

Comment: Does the image of the origin under a Riemann mapping of the disk to the set work?  This is related to some the above and below proposals, but I can’t tell if it’s the same.

Comment: I think it does work, because if two sets are close, there is a small shrinking of both sets such that the Riemann map to the common shrunk set is close to the Riemann map to each set.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving Is that really well-defined, since the Riemann mapping isn't unique?

Comment: Oops, of course: I was hallucinating that it was unique up to rotation, but it’s unique up to rotation and recentering, which is useless.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s an attempt to define such a map which is not an answer but couldn’t fit in a comment.

Consider a Riemann mapping $\varphi:\mathbb{H}^2 \to \overset{\circ}{D}$ (which has a continuous extension to the closure by Carathéodory) and define $F(D) = \varphi( bar(\varphi^\ast\mu_{\mathbb{S}^2}))$. Here $\mu_{\mathbb{S}^2}$ is the spherical measure, $\varphi^\ast\mu_{\mathbb{S}^2}$ is the pulled back measure, and $bar$ is the [barycenter](https://www.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Karl-Theodor_Sturm/papers/paper41.pdf) *. This is well-defined (if the barycenter exists) since the barycenter is geometric and any two Riemann mappings will differ by composition with an isometry of $\mathbb{H}^2$.

- The catch is that the barycenter might not be well-defined if the pullback of the area measure has infinite second moment.

Let’s make another stab at defining such a barycenter that circumvents the issue of having infinite second moment. The Riemann mapping $\varphi$ is conformal, so each point $x\in \mathbb{H}^2$ has a conformal factor $c_x$, and this is well-defined independent of $\varphi$. As $x\to \infty$ in $\mathbb{H}^2$, $c_x \to 0$ (I think this can be deduced from [Koebe’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koebe_quarter_theorem?wprov=sfti1)). There is a unique cutoff $C$ such that $\int_{c_x > C} \varphi^*(\mu_{\mathbb{S}^2}) =\frac12 \int_{\mathbb{H}^2} \varphi^*(\mu_{\mathbb{S}^2}) =\frac12 Area(D)$. Then $U=\{x\in\mathbb{H}^2 | c_x>C\}$ is bounded, and thus $bar(\varphi^*(\mu_{\mathbb{S}^2})_{|U})$ is well-defined.

I believe that this definition should be continuous on $J$, but I haven’t checked it carefully. One issue is that $U$ could change drastically with a small perturbation of $D$, with a little island where $c_x>C$ appearing far from the origin. However, I think the mass of this will be small, so shouldn’t affect the barycenter much. But I certainly haven’t thought this through carefully, and this may be where this proposal breaks down.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice idea and it seems like something along these lines should work.

Comment: The link to the barycenter leads to a paywall with no information about the reference. Could you please spell it out for people without AMS subscription?

Comment: Okay, I found the paper on the author’s website, so I’ve linked to that now.

Comment: Thank you! In case the author changes his website, the paper in question is "Probability Measures on Metric Spaces of Nonpositive Curvature" by Karl-Theodor Sturm.

Answer (score 1):

Igor Belegradek and I just finished another [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.03697) where we construct a continuous point selection from the interior of Jordan domains in Riemannian surfaces, which is equivariant under isometries of the surface, or even conformal transformations in some cases. This is a sequel to the earlier paper mentioned above.

We use equivariant fiber bundle theory, including a theorem of Palais on [slices of proper group actions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/slice+theorem), and conformal mapping techniques based on [Caratheodory's kernel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory_kernel_theorem).
Another approach, using the notion of reach in the sense of Federer, is also discussed for smooth planar domains.

An application is that the space of Jordan curves in a surface of constant curvature admits a strong deformation retraction to the space of round disks in an equivariantly way with respect to the isometries of the surface, which answers a question in a [related post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449024/contractibility-of-the-space-of-jordan-curves).